# Show another div while li hover

Tags: css, mousehover

I have two divs the first one has full of Menu `li` elements and the second one has submenu. When I hover the menu `li` it should show the next div with CSS

```
li:hover{
  //Display Submenu
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/)

Comment: I need to show 'secondDiv' in 'FirstDiv' li:hover

Comment: It's easy when the div is a child of the li: `li div { display:none; } li:hover div { display:block; }` but if it isn't you'll probably need JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want the effect on li:hover or div:hover @JeysinghAnbu

Comment: @sanjeev shetty First div has menu li and second div has submenu. I need to hover first menu div and select second div sub menu. Now it is showing second div. But I can't move to second div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/yv6pyk7a/

```
.secondDiv:hover {
    display:block;  
}
.secondDiv > li:hover {
    background: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Just check this one. Hope it solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks you Praveenkumar, justtry,  imGaurav, sanjeev shetty, Steevan,

Comment: Gud job PraveenKumar :)

Answer (score 1):

Check with the below link just as you want.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/3/)

```
    .FirstDiv:hover + .secondDiv {
    display:block;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I can't move to the second div.  It shows correctly

Comment: Wr do you want to move your second div can you please explain.

Comment: Yes. I need to hover second div while li hover on the first div. It is like menu submenu vertically

Comment: Displaying it on li:hover not on div:hover. @Steevan

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/7/

```
.FirstDiv:hover + .secondDiv {
    display:block;  
}
.secondDiv:hover {
    display:block;  
}
```

Comment: Displaying it on li:hover not on div:hover.

Comment: If on li then you need js, as css can't got to the upper level, here it is: 
http://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/5/

Comment: Yes. You need jquery as css cant go back to parent tags.

Comment: when scroll comes I can't move to the second div. http://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/9/

Comment: If you are ok with div hover (not li), then variant without js is good https://jsfiddle.net/54f3owv4/10/

Comment: Yup. I used Div:hover without javascript. Thank you @justtry

Answer (score 0):

```css
.FirstDiv{
    float:left;
 height: 200px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 border: 1px solid;
 width:500px;
    position:relative;
 
}
.secondDiv{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid;
     height: 200px;
    width:200px;
     background: #FF2200;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:10px;
}
li{
    height:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}

.menu:hover .secondDiv,
.menu:hover ~ .secondDiv {

    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
<div class="FirstDiv">
    <ul>
    <li class="menu"> Menu 1 
        
        <div class="secondDiv">
    Second Div 1 <br/>
    Sub menus
</div>
        
        </li>
    <li class="menu"> Menu 2 
        <div class="secondDiv">
    Second Div 2<br/>
    Sub menus
</div>
        
        </li>
    <li class="menu"> Menu 3 
        <div class="secondDiv">
    Second Div 3 <br/>
    Sub menus
</div>
        </li>
    <li class="menu"> Menu 4
        <div class="secondDiv">
    Second Div 4<br/>
    Sub menus
</div>
        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<d
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. it shows the second div. But I need to select the second div submenu. the second div will have sub menus. I need to select that. Now I can't move to the second div.

Comment: @JeysinghAnbu,  I have edited my answer please check